# Display Images in imageview

Tags: android, json

I am making this post in utter anguish and scorn. Coming to question, I have 2 apps of a hotel, one a customer and other an admin one.

Customer can view categories of food, various items in food and henceforth order them. Admin can add categories, add items in it, etc. This is a part of flow.

The problem , however is like this:
The images of categories and items in it seems to be somwehere else,seen in the logcat (path starts from 54.163), and the other PHP files are on different server.

One tedious & consuming solution suggested was: Bring it down to localhost. Throw everything onto localhost from the server.

Given, I don't have access to server wherein all php files are stored, which does all the API work.

Suggestion #2: Keep Images in android asset folder and load them as per URL.
I don't get the above one.

So, how can I display the images?

Please, do suggest solutions, as I am in dire need. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Somebody please help..

Comment: do you have FTP server access?

Comment: Like FileZilla? I'm a beginner in these things, so please forgive.

Comment: yes if you have any FTP server access you can download image from there and display the imageview

Comment: Yeah, I have those images with me, no need to download. The thing is that those images are there on that server too, on which php files are there. But in config.php, they have mentioned a different path.

Comment: then you need to check with the URL path

Comment: I checked the URL path for images, it's down.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143947/discussion-between-karan-chapaneri-and-user-android).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer. Did the tedious way. Brought it down to localhost. DB into phpmyadmin and all files under xampp->htdocs!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need some image loading library like glide , Picasso etc for loading images in imageView , Using these libraries are so simple.
Like

In Picasso `Picasso.with(context).load("http://your url").into(imageView);`

url : [Picasso Github Url](http://square.github.io/picasso/)
AND

In Glide

```
Glide.with(this).load("http://your url").into(imageView);
```

url : [Glide Github Url](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is not using libraries. In fact, picasso per se is used. But the problem here is "your url".The URL for images, doesn't hold these images now.

Comment: You can add Drawables as well into the imageView using Picasso if your URLs dont work as of now (such as placeholders)

Comment: @tarunjoshi There are approx. 250 images, not more than 4 MB

Comment: @DJO Yes, that's possible, but how do I do that? Given that I'm using recycler view that uses a single row xml, that produces multiple instances. It's not like 2-3 imageviews that I can directly add images.

Comment: @KARANCHAPANERI You will probably be having your custom recyclerView adapter class. In the recyclerView adapter, in the onBindViewholder method, you have access to a row's viewholder and the position of the row. Using position, you can get your object from the dataset and using the viewholder, you can set images into an ImageView. I am assuming you are using the viewholder pattern.